# Direct state access for draw* functions?

Tags: opengl

Now that we have direct state access I wonder why there are no updated glDraw* DSA functions.

For example `glDrawArrays` is dependent to the current VAO, so why is there no `glNamedDrawArrays`?

Do I still have call

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(..);
```

or is there another way?

Comment: I think you may be over-thinking DSA. If you wanted to implement a draw command with zero side effects it would also have to take a handle to the GLSL program to use so that you did not also have to call `glUseProgram (...)`, an array of textures to bind to each image unit and so on. DSA is more for changing object states without binding said object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

glDraw* is just tell OGL to draw something under current context and that maybe related many states like Shader, Blender, VBO/VAO, Z/Stencil, Texture, etc.. Even a tiny change may bring different render result, so you can image DSA glDraw* will be a long function parameter list, that's not good. For example, you want to change cull face from CW to CCW, maybe you need to find the corresponding parameter in a long function call, and change it. Be note, OGL is most C-like, and default parameter feature of function is limited, each time you call DSA glDraw*, you need to have a long function call with most same values, that will make you crazy.

As @Andon M. Coleman mentioned, DSA aimed for reduce the call sequence of general OGL function call type: bind->modify->unbind, and DSA only need 1 API call. That will reduce the CPU time, especial you have a very large OGL API calls.

Thanks
An

Comment: Many-parameter functions is not an excuse: nobody stops you from passing a structure as a parameter, maybe having it initialized via some "glInitState" function.

Comment: The difference between OGL context and this structure is that different threads would be able to pass their structures to the API functions without requiring any locks, while to the context is normally shared (otherwise you'll have to duplicate resources).

Comment: Well, multithread is another topic, especially it goes with OGL, that will make thing complex, ;)